# What's the best place to find Git reference content online while kernel.org is down?

Tags: git

I like reading man pages nicely formatted in a browser instead of in my terminal console.

Until recently, any time I had to look up details of a Git command, I'd just Google the command (like "git reset") then hit the kernel.org link to the nicely formatted man page ( link www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.1/git-reset.html)

Kernel.org's been down for a long time, and it's not clear whether/when it's coming back.

Fortunately the Google caches are still around. But is there another good place to find the Git command references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now an official online location for the Git man pages again - they're at:

- http://git-scm.com/docs

Now if only there were redirects from the old locations on kernel.org, that would stop the links on hundreds of StackOverflow answers being broken :(

Update: such redirects were [requested on the git mailing list](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-scm-com-refresh-tt7528947.html#a7532062) and Scott Chacon's reply indicates this is intended...

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks. (I haven't tried the kernel.org links in a while; Google searches seem to resolve to other resources now. But the site you're suggesting seems to have a nice layout.)

Answer (score 6):

It has been mirrored here: http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html, also check out http://gitref.org/

Answer (score 3):

`git subcommand --help` is the best reference.

(this brings up the same man page in your browser that you would see in kernel.org)

Comment: @John Hinnegan - op says he searches for `git subcommand` on google and goes to kernel.org. Usually, that is what I do as well.

Comment: nm, I'm an idiot / brainfart.  Without thinking, I actually copy-pasted `git subcommand --help` to see what would happen, and got nothing.  (as opposed to actually thinking `git [Sub in a subcommand here] --help`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow instruction here: http://help.github.com/install-git-html-help/

That will install local versions of the html git man pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can also launch your browser to the local version of the docs that are installed by git:

```
$ git help git -w
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [git-scm.org](http://git-scm.org) and the official [Git Reference](http://gitref.org).

Another worthy site is Scott Chacon's community book [ProGit](http://progit.org)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an app like Bwana to bring your local man pages into your browser: http://www.bruji.com/bwana/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the way back machine (archive.org). It is much better way to browse than Google Cache while a site is down.

```
http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://kernel.org
```