# Where are the Git man pages online?

Tags: git, manpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best place to find Git reference content online while kernel.org is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533660/whats-the-best-place-to-find-git-reference-content-online-while-kernel-org-is-d)

Since https://www.kernel.org/ was offline last month, the Git manual pages are no longer available on that site. These were the man pages rendered into HTML for easy browser viewing.

Where is an equivalent place to find those man pages now? There are still zillions of links pointing to the old pages on kernel.org.

Comment: sigh... I looked for duplicates before posting. Really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html

> The official and comprehensive reference manual comes as part of the Git package itself

Answer (score 1):

Scott Chacon has set up a mirror on github until kernel.org is restored completely: http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html

Answer (score 0):

```
linux.die.net/man/1/
```

seems to have at least the major ones.  Just append git-command.  E.g. [linux.die.net/man/1/git-pull](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-pull)

Google also seems to find this if I search [man git-pull].

Finally, if you have a full git installation, you can do `git help -w command` to get the HTML documentation. E.g.

```
git help -w pull
```

Comment: I've seen that, but the die.net manual pages are littered with ads and are hard to read.